# How to remove scratches from bathroom tiles?

Tags: bathroom, tile, scratches

I recently tried to clean some water from my bathroom floor with paper towel, but it left scratches on the floor (see below). Any suggestions on how to get rid of these marks ?

[image]

Comment: It may be the photo, but those look like smudges. Have you tried a degreasing cleaner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is ceramic tile, there is simply no way that a paper towel "scratched" the surface.  Ceramic is among the hardest materials on earth and there are very few things that can scratch it.

If this is tile, then it's just something on the surface.  A good quality tile cleaning product should remove it.

If this tile is some other material, then it's possible, although remotely, that it was scratched.  In that case there are commercial scratch remover products, which are basically very fine abrasive, that you can use to polish it out.  As always with such a product, consult the manufacturer of the flooring product for the best choice and test is on an inconspicuous area first.

Comment: If it's truly scratched and not just a smudge, there's already got a fantastic polishing agent in almost everyone's bathroom - toothpaste. If a good cleaner won't get the smudges off, then toothpaste is a _very_ fine abrasive, often used for cleaning jewelry. Put some on your (old) toothbrush and give that tile a good scrubbing, just like you would your teeth. If you use your _current_ toothbrush to do this, my recommendation would be to put it away in the junk drawer as the "old" toothbrush when done and grab a new one from the cabinet. ;)

Comment: there is also cleaning paste availalbe where household cleaners are sold, also paste can be used with a rag instead of a brush.